# RX63N has NAND or NOR internal flash?

Tags: flash, flash-memories, renesas

I need to read the internal flash of RX63N MicroController multiple times. It will always be the same data block. I was concerned about the life of the internal flash, wearing out etc. I read that [NOR flash is durable](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/162415/will-reading-serial-flash-memory-wear-it-out). Hence would like to know what type of flash is used in RX63N.

I could not find any information about this in datasheet [R01DS0098EJ0180](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/doc/products/mpumcu/doc/rx_family/r01ds0098ej0180_rx63n631.pdf) (Rev.1.80, May 13, 2014)

Comment: Have you read product literature about it. If so, please leave links to what you have read so that nobody repeats your fruitless exercise. If you haven't read any product literature, why not?

Comment: Usually when they talk about durability they are referring to write cycles, not read. Microcontroller memory may be read millions of times while running, MCUs wouldn't be very useful (in general) if they only lasted a few hours/days.

Comment: I read about 'Read_disturb' phenomenon. Hence the concern